# Is onResume() called before onActivityResult()?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-lifecycle, activity-lifecycle

Here is how my app is laid out:

1. onResume() user is prompted to login
2. If user logs in, he can continue using the app
   **3. If the user logs out at any time, I want to prompt login again**

How can I achieve this?

Here is my MainActivity:

```
@Override
    protected void onResume(){
        super.onResume();

        isLoggedIn = prefs.getBoolean("isLoggedIn", false);

        if(!isLoggedIn){
            showLoginActivity();
        }
    }
```

Here is my LoginActivity:

```
@Override
        protected void onPostExecute(JSONObject json) {
            String authorized = "200";
            String unauthorized = "401";
            String notfound = "404";
            String status = new String();

            try {
                // Get the messages array
                JSONObject response = json.getJSONObject("response");
                status = response.getString("status");

                if(status.equals(authorized)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You have been logged into the app!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    prefs.edit().putBoolean("isLoggedIn",true);

                    setResult(RESULT_OK, getIntent());
                    finish();
                }
                else if (status.equals(unauthorized)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "The username and password you provided are incorrect!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     prefs.edit().putBoolean("isLoggedIn",true);
                }
                else if(status.equals(notfound)){
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Not found",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                     prefs.edit().putBoolean("isLoggedIn",true);
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            } catch (NullPointerException e) {
                System.out.println(e);
            }
        }
    }
```

After the user has successfully logged in:

```
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "BOOM SHAKA LAKA!",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

The problem is, onResume() is called before onActivityResult() so when the user has successfully logged in, my main activity does not get notified because onResume() gets called first.

Where is the best place to prompt for login?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

The call to onActivityResult happens before onResume, actually (see [the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent))). Are you sure you're actually starting the activity you wanted with `startActivityForResult` and that you're setting the result of the invoked activity to `RESULT_OK` before returning a value to your activity? Try just putting a `Log` statement in your `onActivityResult` to log that value and make sure that gets hit. Also, where are you setting the value of the `isLoggedIn` preference? It seems like you should be setting that to `true` in your login activity before it returns anyways, but that's clearly not happening.

**Edit**

[The docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult(int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent)) say:

> You will receive this call immediately before onResume() when your activity is re-starting.

Comment: i am setting isLoggedIn after the user has logged in. see my updated code. not sure whats wrong?

Comment: you are right, onActivityResult() is getting called before onResume(). Not sure why my prefs are being read wrong then?

Comment: Note that `onActivityResult` is also called before `onStart`, which is considered to be a bug by many people: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=17787

Answer (score 32):

With fragments it isn't even as simple as `onActivityResult()` being called before the call to `onResume()`. If the activity that you are returning to was disposed of in the interim, you will find that calls to (for example) `getActivity()` from `onActivityResult()` will return null. However, if the activity has not been disposed of, a call to `getActivity()` will return the containing activity.

This inconsistency can be a source of hard-to-diagnose defects but you can check the behaviour of your application by enabling the developer option "Don't keep activities". I tend to keep this turned on - I'd rather see a `NullPointerException` in development than in production.

Answer (score 2):

You may want to consider abstracting away the login state from the activity. For example if a user can post comments, let the onPost action ping for login state and go from there, instead of from the activity state.

Answer (score 0):

Callback methods like `onResume` are not suitable places to achieve the requested functionality.
I would suggest making a class & adding the sign-in/sign-out functionality there.
when a signout callback is received, then call the sign-in functionality.