# Android P onStart called before onActivityResult

Tags: android, android-activity, onactivityresult, activity-lifecycle

I am trying the new Android P Developer Preview, and the secenario is as follows:

1. I call *Activity B* from *Activity A* with **startActivityForResult**
2. Finish *Activity B* with *SetResult* and go back to *Activity A*, the Activity Life cycle used to be (Prior to Android P Preview):

   1. *onActivityResult*
   2. *onStart*
   3. *onResume*

(Here also a post that confirms this order [Execution order of OnActivityResult and OnResume](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16340732/execution-order-of-onactivityresult-and-onresume)) answer from rndstr

3. Now While testing the **Android P Preview** the Activity lifecycle is:

   1. *onStart*
   2. *onActivityResult*
   3. *onResume*

Android Documentation https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity#onactivityresult
says **only**  that *onActivityresult* should come before *onResume*, it says nothing about *onStart*

can anybody help ? is this a bug in Android P Preview or this is a new behavior? is there a good documentation for this?

*I am using targetSDK: 23*

*Activity A is: SingleTask and Activity B is: SingleTop*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds to me like you've answered your own question!

> The documentation says **only** that `onActivityResult()` will be called
>   before `onResume()`, it says nothing about `onStart()`.

`onStart()` and `onStop()` are only called if your `Activity` is not visible. This means that if you launch another `Activity` and that `Activity` does not completely cover the screen, your `Activity` will NOT get the `onStop()`, `onRestart()` and `onStart()` calls anyway. Therefore you should not rely on them and you should not rely on the order in which they are called.